# How are the services distributed in an intra-cluster couchbase server?

Tags: couchbase

I have been studying Couchbase Server.

I found that there are some words that help us get through with the architecture  of it. 
I wanted to know, in a intra-cluster, what means an active and replica vbuckets? How do these work with the services that exist in each node?

Answer (score 2):

vbuckets, as you know, are Couchbase Server's data partitioning mechanism.  The **Data Service** is responsible for managing the vbuckets, active and replica, across all nodes running the Data Service. The active vbuckets store the documents.  The replica vbuckets increase availability of those documents.

In the event of a node failure, replica vbuckets may be promoted to active vbuckets, this is called **Failover**. Or the replica vbuckets may be used when a failed node is replaced by a new node and the cluster is **Rebalanced**, restoring the active vbucket in the new node.

A node running a Data Service has a **Projector** and **Router** process that monitors document mutations and reports relevant changes to the **Index Services** so they can update their indexes.

The **Query Service** handles **N1QL** queries. It uses the Index Service to perform scans and the Data Service to retrieve data from active vbuckets.

With **Couchbase Community Edition** you have to run all the services on each node in the cluster, while the **Enterprise Edition** lets you pick and choose which services to run on each node. This Enterprise feature is **Multidimensional Scaling**.

This image shows **some** of the interactions between the three services.  It does not show the Query Service interaction with the Data Service, though.

[image]

**Clients** have **Cluster Maps** that help them find data and services in the cluster. The cluster map, for example, knows in which active vbucket a document belongs (by creating a hash from the document key or ID). It also knows where the replica of that document resides, if there is a replica. Clients may use the replicas if data retrieval from the active vbucket is too slow or that node has failed.